# How (if) is it possible to retrieve via YouTube API Video of a specific size(big one)?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to retrieve and specify size of YouTube video?
Normally API gives me videos in small resolution 360p.

But I need way bigger 1080p would be my weapon of choice.
Do you know if it's possible to get this size?

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple APIs, so it depends on which you are using. But the embed API has a javascript method to set the quality:

```
setPlaybackQuality(hd1080);
```

Read more about the embed-API here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html

Comment: it's a partial solution, I need to stream this video to a different device so I need to support Data API. http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java.html Here I found an answers. Thanks for help :)!